# Search column but exclude list of words in another column

Tags: google-sheets, array-formulas, google-query-language, google-sheets-formula

I have a function that looks at keywords in multiple columns, and lists all unique versions alphabetically in one list. This is the function I have so far:

```
=unique(sort(substitute(query({A2:A;B2:B}, "where Col1 <>''"),"""","")))
```

I also have a list of keywords in Column C that I do not want to be listed with the function above. What needs to be added to the above to do this?

Answer (score 0):

See if this will do the trick:

```
=unique(sort(substitute(query({A2:A;B2:B}, "where Col1 <>'' and not(Col1) matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, C2:C)&"'"),"""","")))
```

After seeing your data, using this updated formula

```
=sort(unique(query({'Search Console'!A2:A; 'SISTRIX KWs'!A2:A}, "Where not(Col1) matches '"&TEXTJOIN("|", 1, Legend!A2:A)&"'")))
```

Is that what you tried to achieve?

Comment: This doesn't work. It actually brings up more results than it did prior to the change

Comment: Can you share a copy of your spreadsheet? I'm sure that will it a lot easier to find a solution.

Comment: Here is the document: https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1WSnOd86w5FI7xxlln-FlUDV0fdnmeuj6R0Y0mhw8PII/edit?usp=sharing

Comment: Updated my post.

Comment: This didn't work. I need the formula to:
- Look at both columns within Search Console and SISTRIX
- Combine them
- Exclude anything in this list that contains anything within Column A of "Legend"
- Only show unique entries
- Order alphabetically A-Z

Comment: Are you looking for complete or partial matches?

Comment: Seems like I was referencing the wrong sheet. Update my answer again. Please, give it a try.

Answer (score 0):

I figured out how to do it! The end result was:

```
=sort(unique(query({'Search Console'!A2:A; 'SISTRIX KWs'!A2:A}, "Where not Col1 like '%"&TEXTJOIN("%' and not Col1 like '%", 1, Legend!A2:A)&"%'",0)))
```